What IP is really used behind a proxy?
I'm currently working on a project that execute some Http requests.
In order to avoid exposing my own IP, I use a proxy (paid) service. The host is a domain name with a specific port. The service give me the possibility of using a specific login to use a specific IP for the requests. This should give me the assurance of using the same IP during many consecutive HTTP requests.
But, when I try to request different services that display the IP, I'm surprised that some of them show the "right" IP (the one specified in the login), but other display the real host proxy IP (the one that I see when I ping the proxy host).
How is that possible ? Is there a way to trace back from an exposed IP to the host ?

For example, here is a sample config:

Host: myproxy-service.com (=98.76.54.321)
Port: 12345
Login: mylogin_123.456.78.90
Password: XXXX

https://whatismyipaddress.com => 123.456.78.90
https://www.whatismyip.com => 123.456.78.90
https://www.iplocation.net/myip => 123.456.78.90
https://whatismyip.org => 98.76.54.321
http://monip.org => 98.76.54.321
https://www.hashemian.com/whoami/ => 98.76.54.321

Can you check using your browser's DevTools what kind of requests these websites make internally? (Some get it from the main request but some probably make additional XHR requests that might be giving different results.) What does http://echo.opera.com report, and what does https://echo.opera.com report?

http://echo.opera.com display the IP that I see when I ping the host. https://echo.opera.com display another one that is not the one mentionned in the login. None of these url display the IP mentionned in the login, even in another field.

The difference does not seem to came from another way of making the call because if I call https://www.iplocation.net/myip from a tool like postman (which does not execute JS or any thing else than the http request), I get the "login IP", but if I call https://whatismyip.org I get the "Host IP"...

Then that sounds like your login is not functioning correctly, as this site certainly doesn't do anything special to report the address... Does it show any unusual headers in the request that the proxy might be injecting? (For the http URL, of course, not the https one.)

No, nothing special in the headers, I only see the headers I specify in Postman.
I agree with you, when I query echo.opera.com it seems that the login does not work as expecting. But in that case, how does iplocation.net can display the "right" IP, the one associated with the login ?! On this website, it always work as expected...

Most likely because the proxy itself is malfunctioning, and only binding to the correct address half the time.

A proxy server loads the html of a webpage, then forwards that html to your browser and your browser displays it.
To a webserver, the IP is always the server address of the proxy server (the webserver only has a connection with the proxy server; this is a php script for example), but there are a few things that can happen.
The IP address can be queried using javascript. In that case, the script runs locally.
You see your local ip address because it was javascript that looked it up. It is possible the javascript reports that ipaddress back to their server though.
Using a proxyserver is not a 100% foolproof way to hide your IPaddress. If you need a 100% foolproof way, tunnel all your internet traffic over a VPN. That way, even the javascript will report that IP address.

As discussed in comment of the initial post, I don't think that it as anything to do with the way that the IP is get. Because even in a tool like Postman, I don't have the same result depending on the website queried...
